# Avoid options to be taken as argument automatically

Tags: bash

I'd like to do some error checking for a bash script I am writing. In particular, I wish to ensure the following option not to be considered as the argument of an option (intentionally) left empty.

Let's say the following snippet

```
while getopts “hhelpc1:2:” OPTION
do
     case "$OPTION" in
         h|help)
             usage
             exit 1
             ;;
         1)
             var1=${OPTARG}
             ;;
         2)
             var2=${OPTARG}
             ;;
         c)
             test1
             ;;
     esac
done
```

Assuming my script is called test.sh

By doing something like

```
./test.sh -1 -2 dddd -c
```

In the above circumstance test1 output an error message that -2 option is empty. On the opposite, I'd like to raise a warning for -1 being empty, whereas at present -2 will be taken as the argument for -1.

Any help?

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

`getopts`:

1. only handles short option names, so you cannot put "help" in your option string -- that means you're looking for "-h", "-e", "-l", "-p"
2. cannot look for missing arguments the way you're hoping. You'll have to examine $OPTARG to check if it looks like one of your options.

Add a leading `:` to the opt string to handle getopts errors yourself.

Here's a reworking of your code and I'm sure there are plenty of cases I'm not catching

```
#!/bin/bash

usage () { echo usage ...; }
test1 () { echo test1; }

shopt -s extglob

while getopts ":hc1:2:" opt
do
     case $opt in
         h)
             usage
             exit 1
             ;;
         1)
             case $OPTARG in
                 -[hc2]*)
                    echo "error: required argument missing for -1"
                    usage
                    exit 1
                    ;;
                 *) var1=$OPTARG
                    ;;
             esac
             ;;
         2)
             case $OPTARG in
                 -[hc1]*)
                    echo "error: required argument missing for -2"
                    usage
                    exit 1
                    ;;
                 *) var2=$OPTARG
                    ;;
             esac
             ;;
         c)
             test1
             ;;
         :) 
             echo "error: required argument missing for -$OPTARG"
             usage
             exit 1
             ;;
         \?)
             # unknown argument, handle accordingly
             ;;
     esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

echo "var1=$var1"
echo "var2=$var2"
echo "rest=$*"
```

---

Update 2014-01-23

Here's one technique:

```
do_test1=false

while getopts ...
    case $opt in
        ...
        c) do_test1=true ;;
        ...
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

# execute function "test1" if "-c" was given:
$do_test1 && test1
```

Comment: Hey Glenn. You are super. Thanks for this chunk of code. I will review it. Something that I spot immediately is the case -[hc1] for option 1. Shouldn't that be -[hc2]. If not, then I don't get the sense.

Comment: Hi Glenn, one more question. Is there a way to parse all arguments before executing the functional bit? Given the above example, let's say I have a ./script.sh -c -1 aa -2 bb, having the -c as the first argument will trigger the test function before all the rest of the line is read. Of course test can prevent execution if arguments are missing but this won't be the case anymore as soon as -1 and -2 are read. Any hints here?

Comment: The logic test is outside the case statement; so by setting do_test1 to true will make the case statement continuing to parse the arguments and once at the end if do_test1 is true, the && will do execute the script. In such a way, I can introduce a -t (or anything else) to get a second function run. I can also prevent more functions to run during the same cycle as long as an exit bit is added at the end of each function, though I can't guarantee the order. But I guess I have more than I need at present. So thanks.